# NDK - Use of a .so file in a c file

Tags: c, makefile, android-ndk

I'm trying to use a .so file in my C code to use in Java (sorry for my bad English). I created myself a library named `libtest.so` containing one simple function that returns a string named `display()`.

This is my C code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <exp.h> //the header in libtest.so

jstring Java_com_JuionAndroid_TUNandroid_hellondk_Main_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* 
env,jobject this,jstring javaString)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, display());
}
```

And this is my makefile

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test/libtest.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkmain
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmms-0.6.2/native.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I compile it, I get two errors

```
1)error: exp.h: No such file or directory
2)undefined reference to `display'
```

I want to use the .so without it's code so 
I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You may put the `exp.h` with your source file, and include the header file like this:

```
#include "exp.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

1 add the location of exp.h to LOCAL_C_INCLUDES

2 you don't have implementation for display(), you should

a )   implement it

b )   or you should add the library implement it in Android.mk

```
     LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libdisplay              #if is a dynamic library
     LOCAL_LDFLAGS += /path/to/libdisplay.a            #if is a static library
```

Comment: i changed my make file to
`LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)`

`include $(CLEAR_VARS)`
`LOCAL_MODULE := test`
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test/libtest.so`
`include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)`

`include $(CLEAR_VARS)`
`LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkmain`
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmms-0.6.2/native.c`
`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := test`
`include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`

now he recognise the function display but every time i lunch my app it say's cannot find library and library ndkmain not found

Comment: do you have libndkmain.so been built?

Comment: ichanged my makefile to 
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/libtest.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := socket
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/interface.c source/file.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtest
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libtest/jni/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)  But still i am getting the error:undefined reference to display()

Comment: How do you compile the libtest? using the same toolchain in NDK? And could you tell the result of "file libtest.so"?

Comment: and the result of "nm libtest.so | grep display"

Comment: @Gavin yes i am using the same NDK.sry but result of libtest.so mean?

Comment: using nm tool to check the symbol table in libtest.so

Comment: so you have two things to check:1 have you stripped libtest.so? 2 have you implement the display function

Comment: @Gavin yes i have implemented the display function,but to strip libtest.so wht i need to do....
 u can check my question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686265/avoid-using-of-a-for-creation-of-so

Comment: @gavin nw when i made strip --strip-unneeded libtest.so, it gives me **Unable to recognise the format of the input file _libtest.so_**

Comment: @Subratnayak. sounds strange. can you give us your test project for debugging ?