# avoid using of .a for creation of .so

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i have created an android application,here most of my code is in c so i have created it using jni. i have to create `socket.so` file, in which i have to use the `libtest.so`.

while using the `libtest.so` in socket.so i get the `error:undefined reference to function()`. my function() is present inside the `libtest.so`. so to avid this by suggestion i have created my Android.mk as below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := socket
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := source/interface.c source/file.c
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += libtest.a  
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libtest/jni/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but it requires both the `libtest.so` & `libtest.a` file to be present. where as if i am using only the `libtest.a` it works perfectly fine.

since my requirement is to create libtest.so and include it in socket.so can any one please tell me how to avoid dependency of  .a file to create .so file.

if i will comment `LOCAL_LDFLAGS += libtest.a`  then i am getting the `error:undefined reference to function()`

any one plz help me to get out of this problem.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bit unclean.

The shared library (.so) and the archive (.a) are both supposed to contain the same code, but in practice they might not. The first thing you should do is check if the .so really has all the symbols. The linker might have optimized some out. Use the `nm` utility or `objdump` for that purpose.

Can you also post a console dump of the commands ndk-build is executing?

You might also try to avoid what you're doing, as the NDK is not really meant to produce shared libraries that depend on each other. It's possible of course, but the recommended approach is to stuff your libs into static archives and link them directly into the resulting JNI .so.

**Edit:**

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.so` seems wrong. If you want to *link* with a shared library, pass the library to the linker not the compiler: `LOCAL_LDFLAGS += libtest.so` or, even better, `LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -L. -ltest`

Comment: while doing nm -a libxml2.so i am getting no symbols.
but when i have done nm -a libxml2.a i got them.......

Comment: Use `nm -D` for the shared library, or you won't see anything. And don't use `-a` for the static library, that will print debug symbols instead of normal ones.

Comment: Can you compare the output of `nm -D libxml2.so` and `nm libxml2.a`? Do both contain the function symbols you're calling?

Comment: In that case, no idea what's going wrong. Next thing you could try is checking the ndk-build output and see if it's actually linking to your .so. Also, try using -L. -lxml2 instead of passing libxml2.so. Oh, and don't put the .so in your SRC list. It's meant for the linking stage, so add it to LOCAL_LDFLAGS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14526/discussion-between-onitake-and-subrat-nayak)

Comment: hi @onitake , the latest answer given by u to add **LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -L. -ltest** is still not working...it gives me the **error:undefined reference to function()** ....

Comment: Can you post a console transcript so we can see what the compiler is doing?

Answer (score 0):

thanks alot to @onitake.

there was a simple mistake over here was that the libtest.so was not proper(created by code having bugs).

then when i have created a proper libtest.so,

Note:

if some one is having proper .so file and still it gives error then there might be some linking error. So jst remove the line:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libtest/jni/include
```

and put

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libtest/jni/include
```

both of above statements are same but some times it's work.